# I'm trying to import innertext from a td-class. Getting lots of extra text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the innertext of 'wfm-bodyText'.  So, I want to loop through items on a webpage and import, in this case, 'H. Validate Gamer Correct'

[image]

I thought the script below would work, but it actually gives me all kinds of extra text!!

```
Public Sub CopyFromURL()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
Dim thisClass As IHTMLElement2, thisLink As IHTMLElement
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long
row = 1
'Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
'For Each cell In rng

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set TR_col = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TR")

    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")

        row = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            col = 1

            For Each TD In TD_col
                Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
                col = col + 1
            Next
        row = row + 1
    Next

'Next cell
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

The URL is behind a firewall.  I can't share it.

Again, below is the structure of the page.  I want to copy the 'E. Verify phone number if applicable' into my sheet.

[image]

I tried the script below in an attempt to get every element from the page.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://www.SharePoint.aspx"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all

      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

I still can't tell where the relevant data is coming from.

Comment: *actually gives me all kinds of extra text!* - what is the extra text you get?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking at this a lot closer and I'm not even getting the relevant data.  I get all kinds of superfluous data, but I'm not getting what I really want.  I thought this was a TD element, but it doesn't pull in the relevant data.  I guess this is not a TR element either, because I tried that, and I still do not get the relevant data.  I even tried this:
For Each itm In IE.document.all
I thought that would dump all tags and IDs and classes into my worksheet, but again, it skips the data that I really want.  How can I dump the entire contents of a web page into my sheet?

Comment: There is something very weird going on here.  It's almost like the data is sitting on different levels.  Even if I record a macro and pull in the data from the table, the relevant data doesn't come into the sheet.  Even if I record a macro and import EVERYTHING on the entire page, again, the relevant data doesn't come into the sheet.  I've never seen this before.  This is a SharePoint site, so maybe that has something to do with it.  Not sure.

Comment: when I have had issues with this in the past I have looped through every cell (html cell) in every row of every table and done debug.print on each cell to understand what was happening. It was a pain-in-the-ass and took time, but I eventually solved my problem.

Comment: Scott, I just updated my original post with a second script.  I still can't tell where the data is coming from.  Can you post the sample script that you used to grab all the elements from the page?  Thanks.